# MYSQL How can I sum based on multiple criteria by date and by response

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sum the number of hours offered and either accepted or declined based on 3 columns. 1 column is a date 2 column is hours 3 is criteria. I need to sum hours between date ranges where they have accepted or declined OT. I need to be able to count both responses yes and no in the specified date range. @ the 4th sum line it does not work properly and shows wrong counts every other sum line seems to work. It seems that I have more than 2 conditions is fails.

```
SELECT
  employee.employee_ID,
  employee.LastName,
  employee.FirstName,
  employee.Department,
  employee.HomePhone,
  employee.CellPhone,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ot_tracking.shiftDate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31' AND ot_tracking.operatorResponse = 'Yes' THEN ot_tracking.hours else 0 END) AS OT_Accepted,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ot_tracking.shiftDate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31' AND ot_tracking.operatorResponse = 'No' THEN ot_tracking.hours else 0 END) AS OT_Declind,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ot_tracking.shiftDate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31' AND ot_tracking.operatorResponse = 'Not Available - working or off' THEN ot_tracking.hours else 0 END) AS 'OT Unable to work',
  SUM(CASE WHEN ot_tracking.shiftDate BETWEEN '202-12-01' AND '2020-12-31' AND ot_tracking.operatorResponse = 'Yes' OR ot_tracking.operatorResponse = 'No' THEN ot_tracking.hours else 0 END) AS 'OT Offered',
  employee.Senority
FROM site
  INNER JOIN employee
    ON site.siteID = employee.siteID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ot_tracking
    ON ot_tracking.employee_ID = employee.employee_ID
WHERE employee.siteID = 1
AND employee.Department <> 'shop' AND Department = 'Log Yard' AND LogLoader = 'Yes' AND Active = 'Yes'
GROUP BY ot_tracking.operator,
         employee.Senority,
         employee.Department
ORDER BY employee.Department, `OT Offered`, employee.Senority
```

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN ot_tracking.shiftDate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' - line updated

Comment: In the the 4th sum line is this: `'202-12-01'` the exact date that you use? If it is then you missed the final `0` of `2020`.

Comment: I updated the line - typo in the code its 2020-12-01

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose `ot_tracking.operatorResponse = 'Yes' OR ot_tracking.operatorResponse = 'No'` inside parentheses, because the operator `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ot_tracking.shiftDate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31' AND (ot_tracking.operatorResponse = 'Yes' OR ot_tracking.operatorResponse = 'No') THEN ot_tracking.hours else 0 END) AS `OT Offered`
```

or use IN:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ot_tracking.shiftDate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31' AND ot_tracking.operatorResponse IN ('Yes', 'No') THEN ot_tracking.hours else 0 END) AS `OT Offered`
```

'

Comment: I used the IN option and it worked great. Thank you